# Using scrollViewDidScroll to handle multiple Collection View Cells

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview, uicollectionviewcell

I am currently animating the offset of my `UICollectionView` cells with `scrollViewDidScroll`. The Collection View previously just contained 1 `UICollectionViewCell`.

I just added another `UICollectionViewCell` to the same Collection View, and would like to perform the same animation. The problem is, I am getting a crash with error:

```
Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type. Expected DetailedCell but found BasicCell
```

**My progress:**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // First (Detailed Cell)
    for newDetailedCell in mainCV.visibleCells as! [DetailedCell] { // Crashes on this line
        let indexPath = mainCV.indexPath(for: newDetailedCell)
        print("indexPath for Detailed Cell: \(indexPath)")
    }

    // Rest (Basic Cell)
    for basic in mainCV.visibleCells as! [BasicCell] {
        let indexPath = mainCV.indexPath(for: basic)
        print("indexPath for Basic Cell: \(indexPath)")
    }
}
```

**How can I access visibleCells with two differet CollectionViewCells?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
for cell in mainCV.visibleCells {
   if let res = cell as? DetailedCell {
     //
   }
   else 
   if let res = cell as? BasicCell {
     //
   }
}
```

OR

```
let detailCells  = mainCV.visibleCells.filter { $0 is DetailedCell }  
for newDetailedCell in detailCells as! [DetailedCell] {  
    let indexPath = mainCV.indexPath(for: newDetailedCell)
    print("indexPath for Detailed Cell: \(indexPath)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle scroll events for multiple `UICollectionView` implement this condition inside `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    
    if scrollView == collectionView1 {
    
        // Your code goes here
        
    }

    if scrollView == collectionView2 {
    
        // Your code goes here
        
    }

}
```